# Is it possible to search for a string in posts OR postmeta?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

If I have a text string `$search_string` and  construct a query like this:

```
$args = array(
   's'  => $searchstring;
  'meta_query' = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'my_key',
        'value' => $searchstring,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
);

$search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The query will look for posts which find a match for `$search_string` in BOTH posts and postmeta.

Is it possible to change this query so that it looks for matches in EITHER posts or postmeta, not necessarily both.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support that, at least it's not documented. Try to add `'relation' => 'OR',` between those two and see what happens. If it doesn't work, you will probably need to do a good old SQL query, unless you want to make two trips.

Comment: @shanebp, how complicated of `$searchstring` are you looking to support? Is it one word, or multiple terms? Can search operators be used (i.e. `-` to exclude a term)?

Comment: @bosco - I'm trying to extend the basic WP search on a specific page. So basically I need to support whatever the user inputs.

Comment: Ah that makes things somewhat more tricky... Possible, but I think things will get messy. [The logic that parses a search string into SQL](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2103) is not only `protected` within the `WP_Query` class and devoid of actions and filters - it's hard-coded to search post titles, content, and excerpts. Whatever the solution (running two queries and merging the results, creating a custom SQL query, extending `WP_Query`), you'll need to replicate that parsing logic to address post-meta. I'll try my hand at it later tonight

Comment: To clarify, replicating that logic is necessary because a `meta_query` using a `LIKE` comparison operator won't search post-meta the same way that WordPress performs searches on posts - it would rather look for the string in the meta-value as though it were one long search term

Comment: @bosco - yup, was afraid of that. But hope springs eternal. I've already written a custom sql solution but wanted to make sure I wasn't over-looking something obvious.